# pregnant guppy?

Tags: guppies

[image]
I've brought a few female guppies from the pet store today and noticed that one has a dark spot, I was wondering if it could be pregnant or of it has anything else wrong with it

Comment: we have a lot of questions about pregnant guppys,seek and you shall find.and having guppys=pregnant.